# Emulate iOS selenium grid node on a windows VM

Tags: ios, selenium, grid

To test a web application, I have chosen selenium grid.

My application should be tested on android, windows and iOS. I don't have a Mac device and I am not able to virtualise an iOS machine.

Is there any application or another method to configure and iOS node on a windows VM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful for Android Virtual Device (AVD): https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

Also this: https://wiki.mozilla.org/QA/Execution/Web_Testing/Automation/Selenium_Grid

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It turned to be not possible for iOS to test it on a node based on windows OS and it's also impossible to create a VM with iOS in a hardware different from MAC. In summary iOS driver could be only used on a MAC hardware!!